# The best way to listen a websocket API and generate events (Kafka?)

Tags: websocket, apache-kafka

I have a third party API that produces events over websocket. How is the best way to listen and propagate that event inside a Kafka topic?

My strategy is:

- Kafka connects to this API and starts listen to events.
- When an event occurs, Kafka propagate this event to anything that is listen to this topic.

Kafka will be used like a proxy for N APIs propagating to N subscribers.

How is the best way to do this? Kafka have any kind of connector that enables it?